# ¿Como dividir una pantalla en html?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Buen día, estoy implemento para un diseño web que estoy realizando, que la pagina principal apenas ingrese el usuario pueda escojer si irse por "soporte" o por la pagina  "diseño", pero que este dividida en  la misma pagina pero no se como implemetarla en mi html. quien me puede ayudar  ?

Comment: te refieres a que? algun ejemplo o imagen? podrias mejorar ese post, para ayudarte de mejor manera, O estas dispuesto a usar frameworks como bootstrap o bulma para el diseño?.

Comment: Tendrás que aportar más información. ¿A qué te refieres con "soporte" y "diseño"? ¿Puedes poner un esquema del diseño web que quieres conseguir?

Comment: sertía ideal el diseño incial y final que esperas obtener para comprender mejor

Comment: Hola George, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de **[como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Se más especifico, ¿ya has intentado algo?

Comment: Yo lo que realizaría es utilizar iframes y así puedes tener las dos partes en una misma pantalla, puedes tener el código detras de cada iframe y juntar, eso es lo que haría yo